# A Game (similar to tic tac toe) algorithm needed.

Tags: java, algorithm, tic-tac-toe

first of all i'm beginner to Java programming. I want to make an application for School project. I have decided to make a board game! pretty straight forward. 
![Board][1]
 This is the board and there are two player (Both Human). first one player(x) will make his move anywhere on the board. there are 9 places available to him.

motive of the game is to put all three tokens in one line diagonally, horizontally or vertically.

![Winning condition][2]
i want algorithm to check the winner and how to pick value frm user when he makes a move. 
i browsed lots of tic tac toh algorithm but i dont know what goes wrong with them. 
![Posible moves][3]
Please Help!!

Comment: Which part of this are you having trouble with?  Storing the data?  Showing the user interface?  Determining a winner?  Something else?

Answer (score 3):

*Since it's homework, I don't want to just give you an answer.  Also, you weren't exactly clear on what you were struggling with, so I hope this is applicable to the problem(s) you were having.  Edit your answer to make it more clear and/or leave a comment so that all who have answered may improve their answers to suit your needs more effectively.*

You can make use of a two-dimensional array to store the board.  In Java, the syntax for creating a 3x3 two-dimensional array (e.g. using the `char` type, to store `X` or `O`) is as follows:

```
char[][] board = new char[3][3];
```

In Tic-Tac-Toe, there are 8 possible board states that indicate that a player has won the game (moves marked with `X` below):

```
 (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)      (5)      (6)      (7)      (8)
X X X    # # #    # # #    X # #    # X #    # # X    X # #    # # X
# # #    X X X    # # #    X # #    # X #    # # X    # X #    # X #
# # #    # # #    X X X    X # #    # X #    # # X    # # X    X # #
```

Remembering that array indices start at 0 (and go up to 2, since we have a 3x3 2D array), this translates to the following set of conditions:

```
(1): board[0][0] == board[0][1] && board[0][1] == board[0][2]
(2): board[1][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[1][2]
(3): board[2][0] == board[2][1] && board[2][1] == board[2][2]
(4): board[0][0] == board[1][0] && board[1][0] == board[2][0]
(5): board[0][1] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][1]
(6): board[0][2] == board[1][2] && board[1][2] == board[2][2]
(7): board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2]
(8): board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][0]
```

If any of these cells are equal (and are not blank) then someone (either `X` or `O`, depending on who occupies those cells) has won the game.  You could potentially use loops to make this code more compact.

Comment: Because you can only win on your own move you can just search the space around the last placed token.